# TileContainer Cannot set property 'className' of undefined SAPUI5 Version 1.48

Tags: sapui5

My Application was running fine. Now I have changed my SAPUI5 Library to CDN Version 1.48.9.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
>   in TileContainer-dbg.js:1207.

Here is my code:

```
<core:View  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
        xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="sbmobiledashboard.overview" 
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<Page id="overview.page" title="{i18n>pageEventsOverview}" navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress" enableScrolling="false">
    <content>
        <TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
            tiles="{modelTiles>/tiles}">
            <StandardTile 
                    icon="{modelTiles>icon}" 
                    type="{modelTiles>type}" 
                    number="{modelTiles>number}"
                    numberUnit="{modelTiles>numberUnit}" 
                    title="{modelTiles>title}" 
                    info="{modelTiles>info}"
                    infoState="{modelTiles>infoState}" 
                    press="handleTilePress" />
        </TileContainer>
    </content>
</Page>
```

My Result set looks like this:

```
{
d: {
results: [

{

__metadata: {

id: "http://<host>:8003/sap/opu/odata/<namespace>/<service>
/homeTilesSet(guid'000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8838E0')",

uri: "http://<host>:8003/sap/opu/odata/<namespace>/<service>
/homeTilesSet(guid'000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8838E0')",

type: "/<namespace>/<service>.homeTiles"

},

guid: "000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8838E0",

title: "Critical Events (24h)",

icon: "sap-icon://alert",

number: "66 ",

numberUnit: "Events",

info: "Severity critical",

infoState: "Error",

type: "Create"

},

{

__metadata: {

id: "http://<host>:8003/sap/opu/odata/<namespace>/<service>
/homeTilesSet(guid'000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8858E0')",

uri: "http://<host>:8003/sap/opu/odata/<namespace>/<service>
/homeTilesSet(guid'000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8858E0')",

type: "/<namespace>/<service>.homeTiles"

},

guid: "000C29CE-10EA-1ED7-ABA0-EB1B4D8858E0",

title: "Event collection (24h)",

icon: "sap-icon://share-2",

number: "123 ",

numberUnit: "Events",

info: "",

infoState: "None",

type: "None"

},...
```

Debugger tells me that the problem occurs in above listed SAPUI5 Library function. In case I manipulate the result set ot only contain the first tile, the application works.
In previous version 1.30.10 the code and the same result set works fine. I'm wondering what makes it throw an error in the newest library.

Comment: The problem seems to be limited to Chrome. In Firefox it works for me. Maybe a standard bug (?)

Comment: I also see an issue with tiles and the error message 

>  Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

After Upgrade from 1.44.x to 1.52.x of SAPUI5. Probably a regression bug somewhere in the standard. Also tested with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced some issues with 1.48.9 version. If your code works fine with different version try changing the version of SAPUI5 library to 1.48.10. You can change it in index.html in bootstrap section. If this doesn't fix the issue, please post the full error log.

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.48.10/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.xyz": ""}'>
        </script>
```

Comment: I can confirm it behaives different on pervious versions. Looking at the coding that throws the error, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As discovered today the sap.m.TileContainer is deprecated. See documentation: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.TileContainer